# Using "nerve" appropriately

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

Is this sentence grammatically correct "You got the nerves"? The intent is to convey that you have confidence or you are fearless under tough situations

Comment: No - we normally use *singular* in this context. And strictly speaking we should expect the initial *verb* to be explicitly present: ***Have** you got the **nerve** [to do this]?*

Comment: But what if I was saying it in an affirmative way or telling someone that `You got the nerves.` This is without the question mark. Is that grammatically correct?

Comment: It is not idiomatic.  We say "You have **nerve**", not *nerves* or *the nerves*.

Comment: It's worth noting that *"You've **got a nerve**!* means you're ***impertinent / cheeky / presumptive***, not "brave".

Comment: @Fumble But Cambridge dictionary has one of this meaning : `the courage or confidence necessary to do something difficult` for nerve

Comment: But what? ***Nerve*** has a wide range of meanings, among which Cambridge dictionary also gives the definition *the **rudeness** to do something that you know will upset other people*.

Comment: Doesn't the meaning `the courage or confidence necessary to do something difficult` mean nerve could be used to mean brave? As you mentioned it means `...presumptive, not brave.` It sounds like you don't agree with using `nerve` for brave

Comment: "You got the nerves?" sounds like you are mocking someone for being afraid. It's not grammatical, and would be misunderstood. It certainly doesn't convey what you think it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not idiomatic.

"You've got a lot of guts" would be better.  There are a number of vulgar expressions here that I'll won't recommend.

There is an expression if you say "You've got a nerve" it means you are criticising them for being directly rude, self-centred, or for doing something wrong, without caring about the consequences.

Comment: But what if I want to appreciate or point out the courageous quality in someone? Is using `You got the nerve` or `He got the nerve` correct?
Also why is plural `You got the nerves` incorrect grammatically?
Thanks

Comment: No.  "You've got a lot of guts" would be better.  How can I make my answer clearer?

Comment: what are your thoughts about the last comment I posted directly underneath the question? The Cambridge dictionary does mention one of the meanings of nerve to be brave. Although I agree on the sentence you mentioned sounds better